# How to (automatically) get list of MP4 track properties (language) using some scripting?

Tags: macos, video, applescript, mp4

Can someone help me getting the list of track's languages (audio and subtitles) in an MP4 file using some kind of automated scripting (preferable `Applescript` or `Shell script`)?

(I'm building a filemaker database with info about my movies including their languages)

I can do this using `Applescript` and `Quicktime Player (Pro 7)` but I have some movie files that won't open (invalid public movie atom).

Rather than fixing this (doesn't look simple to do and the movies play just fine anyway), I'd like to find an alternate method.

I have been able to get the list of tracks using SublerCLI but it won't show the track's language, e.g.

```
Track: 1, Video Track, 2:10:20.895, 1248 kbit/s, H.264, 1280 x 536
Track: 2, Sound Track, 2:10:20.928, 56 kbit/s, AAC, 2 ch
Track: 3, Subtitle Track, 2:10:13.306, 0 kbit/s, Tx3g, 1280 x 80
```

But that's as far as I've been able to go. Any hint on doing this (using SublerCLI or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

User Case on forum.videohelp pointed me to the MediaInfo utility (http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Mac_OS) which addresses this perfectly and more!